# service instance still null after binding

Tags: android, service, binding

I have a service, and I am trying to bind an activity to it.  The problem is...after running `bindService(..)`, the service instance that Im setting inside the serviceconnection is still null, and I dont know why.

```
private ConnectionService conn;

private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        conn = ((ConnectionService.ConnectionBinder)service).getService();
        Toast.makeText(main_tab_page.this, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
          .show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        conn = null;
    }
  };

@Override
protected void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    //check start connection service
    if(conn == null)
    {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, ConnectionService.class);
        bindService(serviceIntent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

    }
    //connect to server
    server.conn = conn;

    //THIS STATEMENT FAILS: NULL REFERENCE, conn is Null here, and I have no idea why
    conn.ConnectToServer(server);
    server.StartReader();
}
```

Yes: The service is defined in the manifest.

Yes: I can start the service from the MAIN Activity (this code resides in an activity that is started BY the main activity, which is where i need to bind to the service)  I have checked to make sure the service actually does start....it does

According to every example i've managed to locate for bound services, this should be working.  Can anyone tell me why its not?

**Edit: Add service code definition**

```
public class ConnectionService extends Service{

private BlockingQueue<String> MessageQueue;

public final IBinder myBind = new ConnectionBinder();

public class ConnectionBinder extends Binder {
    ConnectionService getService() {
        return ConnectionService.this;
    }
}

private Socket socket;
private BufferedWriter writer;
private BufferedReader reader;


@Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    if(MessageQueue == null)
        MessageQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>();

    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
  }

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return myBind;
}

    //some other code that has everything to do with what the service does, and nothing to do with how it should be started/run
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the service is declared in Manifest.